# power series with conjuguates algebraic coefficients

Tags: power-series, algebraic-number-theory

Let $f$ be a power series with rationnal coefficients ($f\in\mathbb Q[[z]]$) and $\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_s,b_1,\cdots,b_s$ be algebraic numbers.
Let $K$ be a Galoisian field (with Galois group $G$) that such $\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_s,b_1,\cdots,b_s$ belong to $K$.
Is it true that the power series
$$\prod_{\sigma\in G}\left(\sum_{i=1}^s\sigma(b_i)f(\sigma(\alpha_i) z)\right)$$ belong to $\mathbb Q[[z]]$?

Thanks in advance for any answer

Comment: Does Galoisian just mean $K/\mathbb Q$ is a Galois extension? In that case, it suffices to check that power series is invariant under the action of any $\sigma\in G$, which is pretty clear

Comment: Yes, that means this. But I have a problem with the "pretty clear". Can you extend the argument. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Galois group $G$ acts on the ring $K[[z]]$ by acting on the coefficients: $\sigma(\sum a_iz^i):=\sum \sigma(a_i)z^i$.

Let $g\in K[[x]]$. Then $g\in\mathbb Q[[x]]$ if and only if $\tau(g)=g$ for all $\tau\in G$. Thus, it suffices to check that for any $\tau\in G$,
$$\tau\left(\prod_{\sigma\in G}\left(\sum_{i=1}^s\sigma(b_i)f(\sigma(\alpha_i) z)\right)\right)=\prod_{\sigma\in G}\left(\sum_{i=1}^s\sigma(b_i)f(\sigma(\alpha_i) z)\right).$$
I leave this as an exercise for you.

Comment: I dont understand your notation $$\tau\left( \prod_{\sigma\in G}\left(\sum_{i=1}^s\sigma(b_i)f(\sigma(\alpha_i) z)\right)\right)$$. What do you mean with it?

Comment: I defined an action of the Galois group on $K[[x]]$, so the notation $\sigma f$ makes sense, for $\sigma\in G$ and $f\in K[[x]]$.

Comment: I understood. Now I have to manage to do your exercise !!